# Cant use onClick in another class,

Tags: java, android, class, onclick, listener

Im trying to implement the onClickListener for the options_menu to another class but I can't figure out how to do that currently there are two errors within the code that I can't figure out. the first is

```
public class OptionsMenu  implements View.OnClickListener{
```

and the second is

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(OptionsMenu.this, options_menu);
```

ive tried to search around for a fix regarding this but I can't find one or anyone who has had a similar issue with there code. All I'm attempting to do is clean up Home.Java so there is less code in there. Also this is my first time trying to use another class so it will help a lot if I can get through this so I can start a new class maybe?

Home.Java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton options_menu;
private WebView webView;
private EditText search_bar;
private int on = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    options_menu.findViewById(R.id.options_menu);

    //Open in Equinox instead of Deafult Browser
    webView.setWebViewClient(new
            WebViewClient());

    //WebView - JavaScript-WebViewSettings-HomePage
    final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.Google.ca");



    //options button toolbar
    options_menu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.options_menu);
    options_menu.findViewById(R.id.options_menu);
    options_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Home.this, options_menu);

            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,         popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.back:
                            if (webView.canGoBack()) {

                                webView.goBack();
                            }
                            else {
                                webView.reload();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case R.id.forward:
                            if (webView.canGoForward()) {

                                webView.goForward();
                            }
                            else {
                                webView.reload();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case R.id.refresh:
                            webView.reload();
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });

    // settings for keyboard
    search_bar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    search_bar.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            if(arg1 == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)
            {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().contains(".com")) {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://".concat(search_bar.getText().toString()));
                } else {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.ca/search?q=".concat(search_bar.getText().toString()));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    search_bar.requestFocus();
    search_bar.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

}

// Animation of search_bar
public void edit_clicked(View view) {


    EditText search_bar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Home.this, R.anim.edittext_scale);
    search_bar.startAnimation(anim);

}
//Hard Back Button
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else{
        webView.reload();
    }
}
}
```

OptionsMenu.Java

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;


/**
 * Created on 2018-01-05.
 */

public class OptionsMenu  implements View.OnClickListener{

public ImageButton options_menu;
public WebView webView;


public void onclick (View view){
             options_menu.findViewById(R.id.options_menu);
             options_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick (View view){

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(OptionsMenu.this,   options_menu);

            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,   popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new   PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.back:
                            if (webView.canGoBack()) {

                                webView.goBack();
                            }
                            else {
                                webView.reload();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case R.id.forward:
                            if (webView.canGoForward()) {

                                webView.goForward();
                            }
                            else {
                                webView.reload();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case R.id.refresh:
                            webView.reload();
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(OptionsMenu.this,   options_menu); You should pass activity context as the first argument for Popmenu not Optionmenu.class which is just a class.  so it should be PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activty,   options_menu);

Comment: activity cause it have an error still

Comment: How are you passing activity ?

Comment: to be honest this is why I need help with classes cause I don't know....

Comment: create  options menu like below in activity OptionsMenu optionsMenu = OptionsMenu(activity.this, options_menu, webview)

Comment: in the OptionsMenu.Java or Home.Java

Comment: Home.java. We can discuss more over chat

Comment: Message me then idk how to initiate tha t

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really make what your problem is but I've identified some problems within your examples.

First:
`PopupMenu` needs 2 primary object, the first is the `Context` which you can use the `Activity` itself and the second an anchor view to which the PopupMenu should be attached.

```
/* Main.this refers to the current `Main` activity object
 and should be called from within the activity */
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Main.this, imageButton);
```

Second:
You have created an `OptionsMenu` class and you've tried to inflate from your xml layout. Only the object which are `View` or extend `View` can be inflated (`findViewById()`) from the xml and your `OptionsMenu` is not a `View`.

So with that said here is a simple example of how you can inflate a view from xml and handover the `PopupMenu` attachment to a different class.

The class to attach a PopupMenu to a View:

```
public class OptionsMenuHandler{
    public OptionsMenuHandler(Context context, View anchorView) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, anchorView);

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton menuButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crop_image_view);

        menuButton = findViewById(R.id.menuButton);

        new OptionsMenuHandler(TestActivity.this, menuButton);
    }
}
```

Remember this is just to teach you how to use classes.

Comment: if there is a website/link or page to help me more with classes that is greatly appreciated

Comment: There are plenty of resources online. Try googling "java classes and objects".

Comment: there are no errors now but crashes on startup, if I use Main then it come with a error. I extended to AppCompatActivity and I can use OptionsMenu